# Linq to SQL : Uniqueidentifier columns has 0

Tags: sql, database, linq, uniqueidentifier

I have a table with a primary key which was set as a uniqueidentifier datatype. When insert a data inside, the uniqueidentifier field is 0... I looked up the web , I need to assign it by using new Guid() inside the code.

But how does it knows the id will be unique with the data inside the database

Comment: What do you mean by `uniqueidentifier field is 0`?

Comment: If you get clashes between uniqueindentifier and the New Guid() created in code, you're very very unlucky.